# store the output of watson services to ibm database

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I need to store the output  of IBM Watson visual recognition service in ibm cloud or any other database, which can be accessed for further use.Can anyone please help me out? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Cloudant on Bluemix
https://cloudant.com/getting-started-with-cloudant-ibm-bluemix/

Or better yet Compose.io on Bluemix that offers you different DB options and an easy way to migrate between them.

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/07/getting-started-compose-bluemix/

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Recognition service runs on Bluemix, which offers a number of database options. You could start by investigating the Object Storage service: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/object-storage/?taxonomyNavigation=applications.